# upgrade spring-data-common 2.3.x occur error:No accessor to set property private final long

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

```
abstract class IEvent{val timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()}
data class event(val name:String): IEvent()
```

when I upgrade spring boot 2.3.x with spring-data-common 2.3.x
it occur a error when use mongo fetchInto,the trace is

```
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No accessor to set property private final long xxxxxx.timestamp!
        at xxxxxxxxx.Event_Accessor_es4gdm.setProperty(Unknown Source) ~[classes/:?]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.InstantiationAwarePropertyAccessor.setProperty(InstantiationAwarePropertyAccessor.java:104) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RE
LEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ConvertingPropertyAccessor.setProperty(ConvertingPropertyAccessor.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.R
ELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:450) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.
RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.populateProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:367) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.
0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:347) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:317) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:250) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:246) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:98) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDocumentCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:3141) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2746) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFindOne(MongoTemplate.java:2466)
```

**it is only a timestamp that is unnecessary to var**

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. Next time you ask a question or post an answer, please format the code or logs correctly so it's easier to read. Also, what's exactly the question here?

Comment: Thanks a lot,It is my first time to ask, I'll study the usage later.